# Can Flask-Mail make drafts?

Tags: python, flask, gmail, flask-mail

I suspect that this is related to deep philosophy of email, but it's worth a try.

I'm using Flask-mail to send emails from my server via a gmail account. I'd like to be able to push some of those emails into the drafts folder so that I can check them while I'm debugging, and also tweak them on a per person basis.

I realise that I can use [the gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.drafts/create) *instead* of Flask-Mail, but do I have to?

Comment: Flask-mail interacts with an SMTP server. SMTP is a _transfer protocol_ (hence the TP). There is no storage, therefore no such thing as a draft message.

Comment: Makes sense. Is it worth making that an answer?

Comment: I don't think so as it's slightly off-topic and not strictly a programming question anyway. Feel free to answer it yourself for future reference though.